# Natural Relationship between : Mixed Effects Regression and Longitudinal Regression

Tags: regression

I have often seen Mixed Effects Regression models and Longitudinal Regression models being referred to as basically the same thing. I have never quite understood why this is and am trying to figure it out.

I wrote all 3 models out:

1. The **mixed-effects (random effects + fixed effects) regression model** with group-level correlations in the error term can be written as (ith patient in the jth group):

$$y_{ij} = X_{ij}\beta + Z_{ij}b_j + \epsilon_{ij}$$

where $b_j \sim N(0, \Psi_j)$ and $\epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0, \sigma^2_j)$, reflecting the group-level correlations.

2. The **fixed effects longitudinal model** with time correlations in the error term can be written as (the t-th measurement for the i-th patient)  :

$$y_{it} = X_{it}\beta + Z_{it}b_{it} + \epsilon_{it}$$

where $b_{it} \sim N(0, \Psi_t)$ and  $\epsilon_{it} \sim N(0, \sigma^2_t)$, reflecting the time correlations.

3. The **longitudinal mixed effects (random effects + fixed effects) regression model** with time and group-level correlations in the error term can be written as (t-th measurement for the i-th patient in the j-th group):

$$y_{ijt} = X_{ijt}\beta + Z_{ijt}b_{ij} + \epsilon_{ijt}$$

where $b_{ij} \sim N(0, \Psi_{jt})$  and $\epsilon_{ijt} \sim N(0, \sigma_{j,t})$, reflecting both time and group-level correlations.

So is this basically the connection between all 3 models? From a modelling perspective, the time dependence and the group level dependence can be represented through the same parametric structure - and the estimation is therefore done similarly in both (i.e. in both models RMLE is used for random effects and GEE is used for fixed effects).

Is this the correct interpretation? Is this why Longitudinal  Models and Mixed Effects Models are said to be very closely related to one another?

Comment: Yes, I think it is. You can try this by seeing if you get the same result - e.g. results from xtmixed in stata and xtreg, re will be identical. (But xtreg, fe won't).

Comment: To me "longitudinal regression" covers a whole bunch of models, including both your number 2 and 3 and many others - basically any regression that has repeated measures is, in some sense, longitudinal. For that reason, I wouldn't use the term unless in a phrase like "when you have time in your data, you need some sort of longitudinal model".

Comment: @user123945 I do not quite understand your model 2. It seems to contain random effects. And b.it suggests these random effects can be different across time points within patients. Shouldn't that be b.i? And if model 2 also contains random effects, is the name than correct, suggesting only fixed effects?

Comment: i meant to write : a longitudinal model each patient has multiple measurements... but we arent modelling the patients in clusters. is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Wooldridge discusses fixed effects models for longitudinal data in Introductory Econometrics, A modern approach, third ed. Equation 14.4 and 14.5. They contain a fixed effect a.i for "patient" i. Think of this as a dummy for patient i with fixed effect. Each patient having his/her own dummy the regr coeff of which must be estimated. Or instead, the mean Y of patient i is subtracted from each Y value of that patient. This is different from modelling each patient's influence on all his/her Y values by a random patient effect, as in random effect models for longitudinal data.

Comment: The typical wording is "fixed effects models" vs "random effects models" for longitudinal data. Actually I believe, your question is more about how multilevel models (data from pupils within schools, with random school effect) can be used to study longitudinal data (from observations within patients with random patient effect). A nice book which explains this relationship is Applied longitudinal data analysis, of Singer and Willett. Fixed effects models form another branch in the tree of models for longitudinal data.

Comment: thanks for the clarifications ... I was just curious about the following point: mixed effects can be used to describe : students in nested classrooms/schools at a single point in time (Option A), students at multiple points in time without any nesting (Option B), students in nested classrooms/school at multiple points in time (Option C) , Did I correctly write these in my question?